# Proof of stopping theorem for bounded stopping times

Tags: probability, martingales, stopping-times

Let $\tau$ be a bounded stopping time and $X=X_n$ a martingale. Then $X_\tau$ is integrable and $E(X_\tau)=E(X_0)$.

I need help with the proof at discrete time, at one step I am not sure I understood, and also I am new to proving stuff so may you please check I wrote correctly every step?

Suppose $\tau$ is bounded by an integer K, we can write the expectation as:

$E(X_\tau)=E[\sum_{k=0}^KX_kI(\tau=k)] $ because thanks to the indicator the only term which survives is $E(X_\tau)$

$=\sum_{k=0}^KE[X_kI(\tau=k)] $ because of linearity of expectation

$=\sum_{k=0}^KE[E[X_K|F_k]I(\tau=k)]$ because X is martingale, then the book says also because $\{\tau=k\}\in F_k$ but I can't understand why that's important

$=\sum_{k=0}^KE[X_KI(\tau=k)]$ this is what I am not sure about: was it possible to apply like E[E[X|Y]]=E[X]? If so, why the conditions to apply that are satisfied? Thank you in advance, the rest of the proof I understood.

Comment: The argument that $\{\tau=k\}\in F_k$ is used one step later than the step where you write it. There one uses it to apply the general fact that E(E(X|G)I(A))=E(XI(A)) for every sub-sigma algebra G, A in G, and X integrable. Usually, this property is considered as being part of the definition of E(X|G). How do you define E(X|G)?

Comment: you are right, it's the definition of conditional expectation, because $E(X|G)=Y$ we know that it holds $E(YI_A)=E(XI_A)$ for every A in G. In my case my Y is $E(X_K|F_k)$, is that correct?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Argumentation I:**  Since $(X_k)_{k \in \mathbb{N}}$ is a martingale, we have $$X_k = \mathbb{E}(X_K \mid \mathcal{F}_k) \qquad \text{for all} \, \, k \leq K. \tag{1}$$ Consequently, $$\mathbb{E}(X_k 1_{\{\tau=k\}}) = \mathbb{E}(\mathbb{E}(X_K \mid \mathcal{F}_k) 1_{\{\tau=k\}}).$$

In the next step, we use that $\{\tau=k\} \in \mathcal{F}_k$. In fact, $\{\tau=k\} \in \mathcal{F}_k$ implies

$$\mathbb{E}(\mathbb{E}(X_K \mid \mathcal{F}_k) 1_{\{\tau=k\}}) = \mathbb{E}(\mathbb{E}(X_K  1_{\{\tau=k\}}) \mid \mathcal{F}_k)) \tag{2}$$

(this is called *pull-out*). Finally, recall that for any integrable random variable $X$ and for any sub-$\sigma$-algebra $\mathcal{F}$ it holds that

$$\mathbb{E}(\mathbb{E}(X \mid \mathcal{F})) = \mathbb{E}(X).$$

Applying this in $(2)$, we get

$$\mathbb{E}(\mathbb{E}(X_K \mid \mathcal{F}_k) 1_{\{\tau=k\}}) = \mathbb{E}(X_K  1_{\{\tau=k\}}).$$

**Argumentation II:** Recall that $$\int_F Y \, d\mathbb{P} = \int_F X \, d\mathbb{P} \qquad \text{for all} \, \, F \in \mathcal{F} \tag{3}$$ for $Y = \mathbb{E}(X \mid \mathcal{F})$. Applying this with $X = X_K$, $\mathcal{F} = \mathcal{F}_k$ and $Y:=X_k = \mathbb{E}(X_K \mid \mathcal{F}_k)$, we get

$$\mathbb{E}(X_k 1_{\{\tau=k\}}) = \mathbb{E}(X_K 1_{\{\tau=k\}})$$

as $\{\tau=k\} \in \mathcal{F}_k$.

Comment: Thank you, can't we directly take advantage of the fact I have something in the form of the definition of conditional expectation where $E(X|G)=Y$ and $E(YI_A)=E(XI_A)$ where my Y here is $E(X_K|\mathcal F_k)$ and my X is $X_K$ and my set A is $\{\tau=k\}$ so I can directly write $\mathbb E( \mathbb E (X_K|\mathcal F_k)I_{\{\tau=k\}})=\mathbb E ( X_KI_{\{\tau=k\}})$

Comment: @Drush Yes, this argumentation is also correct.